# NOOBS SHA256 does not match because of ver number

Tags: noobs

I'm looking for the correct hashfile for NOOBS 3.5.1
The dl page advertises the zip file as 3.5.0 but downloads 3.5.1
It is 2020-12-19
Can someone point me to the correct hash. I am unable to find a current one.
This is my first Rasberry Pi

Comment: Can you post a link to the page you download from? AFAICT there are no references anymore to NOOBS on the Pi download pages.The most recent version I see in the downloads archive is dated 4-12-20

Comment: Any reason to use NOOBS? PINN is much better...https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinn/ and RPF seem to be deprecating it as its no longer on https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/

Comment: @Dirk Its still in the downloads page at https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/ - if  the pages get any simpler they will become and advert!

Comment: Thank You for your help. The hash below is the one I was looking for. FYI I _DID_ download at [https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) today and would like to point out the page shows offline and network download ver 3.5.0 and the download, today, was 3.5.1. The hash that is published on that page must be for 3.5.0. Sorry, I am not yet to the point of building from git. Thank you for providing the hash that matches the download that I obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the files in [the NOOBS archive](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS/images/NOOBS-2020-12-04/)

The hash values are:

**SHA1**:

eec0a97c0ca5d36905cf28b64e69eb80047cd290  NOOBS_v3_5_1.zip

**SHA256:**

1c3197f1809abdcd4a16a04dba1800dabcac0d47437406f4837dfcab7dbd9339  NOOBS_v3_5_1.zip

Note as at 19-12-2020 only the full version of NOOBS (i.e. 'offline and network install' or with OS built in) is stored in the archives - size is reported at 2.6G

Source files on [GITHUB](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs) are still available if you want to build it and infer version 3.5 going by the change date / tag history.

Comment: At the current rate it is going to take me four hours (and climbing) to download the full version of NOOBs from the site! The Lite version is 3.5 (from BUILD-DATA in the zip -Build-date: 2020-09-15 NOOBS Version: v3.5) and the SHA256 of my file matches the web value.